# Find the string and get data

Tags: excel

I have 2 excel worksheets.

```
Sheet 1
Column A = ID number
Column B = Name

Sheet 2
Column A = Name
Column B = ID Number
```

Sheet 1 is database for all the ID numbers and name in the system
And in sheet 2, I just want the Id numbers for the name already typed before.
I don't want to use any macros.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on dynamically assigned name fields and INDEX/MATCH. The dynamically assigned named area will automatically increase when you add additional ID and names in it.

#### 1. Create 2 named areas.

Name 1:
Define names -> Name manager -> *New*
Name: `myID`
Referes to: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A);1)`

Name 2:
-> *New*
Name: `myNames`
Referes to: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B);1)`

#### 2. Insert formula to fetch the ID number.

In cell B2: `=INDEX(myID;MATCH(A2;myNames;0);1)`
Copy this formula down column B ...